# IP Camera (Dahua) is not tuned on, but detected in network

Tags: networking, hardware-failure, ip-camera

I bought an IP Camera (Dahua IPC-HFW1230s) but I experience some problems with it. I plugged in both the Ethernet and the 12V DC power supply (not feeding it through PoE) and try to access it's web interface from http://192.168.1.108 (default address). However, my PC's IP is 192.168.0.100 which is a different class network, so I thought this causes the "Unable to connect" failure. When I ping the camera it returns "Destination host unreachable", but when I "arp -a" it appears in the results with it's physical address. However, I think it is not (completely) turned on, as when I darken the room completely, the IR LEDs are off.

What do you, guys, think? Is the camera off? If so, how can it be turned on?

**Edit**: I tried connecting both devices to a separate network with class 192.168.1.x. Both, the camera and the PC were given static IPs but I still cannot ping the camera or open it's web interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both your PC and the camera need to be on the same subnet.

1) For initial setup, connect the IP camera directly to your PC ethernet port, give your PC a static address in the same subnet (e.g. 192.168.1.1), and point your web browser at 192.168.1.108.

2) The [manual](http://pl.dahuasecurity.com/download/product/20180205/dh-ipc-hfw1230s_operation_manual-_20180124.pdf) says in the *Networking* section that the camera supports both a static IP and DHCP. So for daily use, make sure your network DHCP server (usually your home router) assigns an IP address to the camera via DHCP. Many routers also have the option to give it a name, so in the future you can just access the camera via this name.

Alternatively, give the camera static IP address in your home network, (say 192.168.0.153) and use this in the future.

Additionally, the camera also supports Bonjour (mDNS) and Dynamic DNS (DDNS), so you can use those to access the camera under a name.

If any of the technologies used is unclear to you, read up on them (there's plenty of info online).

**Edit**

If the problem is that you suspect that the camera is not operational:

1) Connect camera directly to your computer, give your computer static IP address as above. Keep the camera disconnected from the power.

2) Start `wireshark` or a similar program on your computer.

3) Power on the camera, watch if you see any packets (e.g. a DHCP request)

4) If not: press reset button on the camera, wait a bit, watch if you see now any packets.

5) `ping` the camera, see if you get an ARP response.

If you neither get a DHCP request nor an ARP response (there may be no DHCP request for initial setup), I'd suspect the camera is broken, and return it. And I don't see any power switch or similar in the manual, but you have the camera in front of you, I don't. Only someone who has the exact same brand and made it work will be able to tell you that with certainty, and chances that someone like this reads this are pretty low.

Comment: The technologies are clear. I see I didn't include an important fact, and will edit my question. I connected them both to a separate network with class 192.168.1.x. The problem is how to make sure the camera is ON? Is there any specific way to plug it in? Should I do something else after I plug it in to turn it on?

Comment: Thank you! The ARP request is from 192.168.8.4 though and the cameras manual says it should be 192.168.1.108. Gave the pc Static IP of 192.168.8.x and was able to connect to the camera. I have always was bad at network diagnostics :) Thanks!

Comment: Guess somewhat already configured it for a different IP address before...

Comment: You mean it's already been used?

Comment: Or tested. Or the manual is wrong. Or for a previous version. Or ...

Comment: @Emil Avramov, if this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as answered. That way other people searching may find it as such, it also gives credit to the person that took their time to answer you.